# Who played the creature in Creature from the Haunted Sea?

Tags: movie, character-identification

In the 1961 Roger Corman film [Creature from the Haunted Sea](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054768/) who played the creature? Neither Wikipedia nor IMDb give any details. It is plausible that the actor is trying to keep this quiet.

[image]

Comment: The IMDB picture credits state Robert Bean. He is also listed as an uncredited boom operator. I corrected IMDB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the Wikipedia page of that movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creature_from_the_Haunted_Sea), Robert Bean, the actor who played Happy Jack Monahan, "also played the role of the Creature", as pointed out in the *Development* section.